# equivalent of dumpstabs -s solaris command in linux

Tags: linux

what is the equivalent of dumpstabs -s solaris command in linux?

Regards
ven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should do the same:

```
objdump -g
```

Or maybe

```
readelf --debug-dump
```

for ELF files. You can give various options to that last command (see `man readelf`).

**Edit**: After reading the manual of `objdump`, I found the `-G` option to show the STABS (I guess this is what you want). The manual mentions the following:

> This is only useful on systems (such as Solaris 2.0) in which ".stab" debugging symbol-table entries are carried in an ELF section.

So maybe what you want just isn't possible on Linux.

Comment: for objdump -g  i am getting 

objdump -G a.out
a.out:     file format elf32-i386

Comment: @venkat: I guess you won't find a tool that will be 100% equivalent with `dumpstabs` but I think you should be able to get the information you want using the tools I mentioned. Read the `man` pages of those tools (especially about the options you can give to `readelf --debug-dump`).